# Result pass Callback

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, closures

How can call that commeneted line : result(paymentMethods)?

Same with error I want to pass. I tried it but not able to understand.

Please help

```swift
private func getPaymentMethods(result : FlutterResult){
        var paymentMethods :[AnyHashable:Any] = [:]
        var errorDescription: String = ""
        AppDelegate.pay.getPaymentMethods(withOptions: nil, withSuccessCallback: { methods in
             paymentMethods = methods
            //result(paymentMethods)
        }) { error in
            errorDescription = error
        }
    }
```

This is actual method I'm trying to call

```swift
 @objc final public func getPaymentMethods(withOptions options: [AnyHashable : Any]?, withSuccessCallback success: @escaping ([AnyHashable : Any]) -> Void, andFailureCallback failure: @escaping (String) -> Void)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this to get results back

```
private func getPaymentMethods( result :@escaping ([AnyHashable:Any])-> Void){
        var paymentMethods :[AnyHashable:Any] = [:]
        var errorDescription: String = ""
        self.getPaymentMethods(withOptions: nil, withSuccessCallback: { methods in
             paymentMethods = methods
            result(paymentMethods)
        }) { error in
            errorDescription = error
        }
    }
```